# This site can’t be reached for AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was paused an AWS Laravel application from elastic beanstalk by making max instance 0.
And now I want to resume it, and when I made max instance 1, EB create the instance, and I setup the security group to handle ssh port 22 and http port 80, so now the instance is accessible by ssh and all is well, but the environment URL form elastic beanstalk not respond and gives me "This site can’t be reached"

And my security group is

[image]

So why I see "This site can't be reached"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries I paused and resumed the elastic beanstalk again, and I make rebuild environment, so it working well now

And my security group created automatically by EB to be like this

[image]